# Adding File in HTML from Parent Directory using DOT Syntax

Tags: html

While working on a Node Project , I came across this

`<script src="../../file.js" type="text/javascript">
 <script src=".file.js" type="text/javascript">
 <script src="../file.js" type="text/javascript">`

Could You describe what all this means ?

Thanks

**Edit**
Solved My Confusion
https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: Relative paths ...